# Select button by highest number in xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

There are multiple buttons on my page containing similar href. They only differ with id_invoices. I want to click one button on page using xpath and href which looks like:

```
href="/pl/payment/getinvoice/?id_invoices=461"
```

I can select all buttons using:

```
invoices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/payment/getinvoice/')]")
```

but I need to select only button with highest id_invoices. Can it be done? :)

Comment: Store the value in temporary variable and match it with invoices

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about python so giving you a direction/algorithm to achieve same

```
Using getAttribute('@href');
```

You will get strings of URLs

You need to split all element after `getText()` you get in invoice `List`.

`Split by`= and pick up the last array value.

Now you need to typecast string to int, as last value after = will be a number

Now you just need to pick the highest value.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

```
hrefList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/payment/getinvoice/')]/@href")

for i in hrefList:
    hrefList[i]=hrefList[i].split("id_invoices=")[-1]

max = max(hrefList)

driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/payment/getinvoice/?id_invoices="+str(max))+"'"+"]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an XPath that returns all the desired elements, you just need to grab the `href` attribute from each one, split the href by '=' to get the id (2nd part of string), find the largest id, and then use the id to find the element you want and click on it.

```
invoices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/payment/getinvoice/')]")
ids = []
for invoice in invoices
    ids.append(invoice.get_attribute("href").split('=')[2])
results = list(map(int, ids)) // you can't do max on a list of string, you won't get the right answer
id = max(results)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/pl/payment/getinvoice/?id_invoices=" + id + "']").click
```